# Jquery input complicated incrementing mess

Tags: jquery

I have this input that has text and when you click it, the text dissapears but if you didnt type anything the text will come back.

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Answer" />
<input type="text" id="forminput" class="clonedInput" onclick="this.value='';" 
onfocus="this.select()"onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Answer 1
':this.value;" value="Answer 1" />
```

I have a button that clones and increments my current input field using this function.

This is the function incrementing my current input field but i also need to increment the Answer #.

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
var newElem = $('#formanswer' + num).clone().attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum);

// manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum).attr('value','Answer '+newNum);

 // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
 $('#formanswer' + num).after(newElem);
```

My problem is that i need to increment the text inside the new input field to make it dynamically incrementing by one each time it is cloned. Ive been baning the wall against my head for hours but i hope it isnt some easy php var. plz help me :~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle which is working, and I think does what you're attempting:

http://jsfiddle.net/R2tFz/

For posterity, here is the javascript I created:

```
$(function () {

$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
//clone the last field    

var newNum = num + 1; // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    var newElem = $('#formanswer' + num).clone().attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum);

// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

// manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
$("input", newElem).attr('name', 'formanswer' + newNum).val('Answer ' + newNum);

 // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
 newElem.insertAfter($('#formanswer' + num));

});


    $(".clonedInput").live('blur', function () {
     var num = $(this).attr('name').replace('formanswer', '');
     $(this).val( (!$(this).val().length)?('Answer '+num):$(this).val() );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: dang dude, your the best! i was unsure how to even approach the problem. thanks for showing it in js fiddle 2.

Comment: :( this function does not have IE8 browser support. im not sure of any others because i only have IE8 and firefox. y cant everyone use the greatest browser ever... FIREFOX!

Comment: Well... what happens in IE8?  I suspect it is because I named the input the same as the id in the wrapping div.  Try changing that to something else.

Comment: ill work on it but your still the best. now i have a serious shot at making this work thanks to your function.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult for me to tell what you are doing in your javascript here because I can't see the id `formanswer` anywhere and I don't know anything about your HTML other than the fact that you have an input with some event attributes on it.

Because of this I can't test your code so have written my own quick solution. I hope it will help you.

It does what I think you want it to do (The button create a new input after the last one and increments the number in the placeholder text and id attribute).

I'm sorry if I have mis-understood.

```
<input type="button" class="add" value="Add Input" />
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="form_answer_1" class="answer_input placeholder" title="Answer 1" />
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        placeholder();

        $('.add').click(function() {
            var count = $('.answer_input').size() + 1;
            $('#container').append('<input type="text" id="form_answer_' + count + '" class="answer_input placeholder" title="Answer ' + count + '" />');
            placeholder();
        });
    });

    function placeholder() {
        $('.placeholder').each(function() {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
            $(this).css({'color': '#777'})
            $(this).focus(function() {
                if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }

                $(this).css({'color': '#000'});
            });

            $(this).blur(function() {
                if($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
                    $(this).css({'color': '#777'});
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```