# Jquery input complicated incrimenting mess

Tags: jquery

I have this input text field that will initially say Answer 1 then if you `focus()` the text will disappear. If you `blur()` the text will come back.

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Answer" />
      <div id="formanswer1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">Answer:<input type="text" id="formanswer1" value="Answer 1" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Answer 1':this.value;"/></div>
</div>


<script>

$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('#formanswer' + num).clone().attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum).attr("onblur","this.value=!this.value?'Answer "+newNum+"':this.value;");

    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum).attr('value','Answer '+newNum).attr('onblur',"this.value=!this.value?'Answer "+ newNum +"':this.value;");

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#formanswer' + num).after(newElem);

});

</script>
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to incriment the `onblur()` value. I'm not sure if I have the syntax wrong but I cant figure this one out.

Comment: Why are you asking this question again?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529986/jquery-input-complicated-incrementing-mess

Comment: I provided you a working example of exactly this on your first posting

Comment: Don't use `.attr` to attach event handlers. Use the actual event handler functionality, e.g. `.blur()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead direct Js use this for onblur

.attr('onblur',function(){

this.value=!this.value? "Answer"+ newNum:this.value;
});

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Answer" />
<div id="formanswer1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">Answer:<input type="text" id="formanswer1" value="Answer 1" /></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input#formanswer1').on('click',function(){
       $(this).val("");
});


$('input#formanswer1').on('blur',function(){
    if($(this).val() === ""){
        $(this).val("Answer 1")
    }
});
```

check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gSQ94/12/